# Running ArcGIS API for JavaScript locally?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm pretty new to arcgis javascript api, and I'm wondering how to run it locally.
I have downloaded the api, and put the folder "arcgis_js_api" in the root folder of my apachi server, and edited the files "init.js" and "dojo.js" and replace the strings '[HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI]dojo' to 'localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.12/3.12/' as said in the documentation. But still it won't work. am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must replace '[HOSTNAME_AND_PATH_TO_JSAPI]dojo' with 'localhost/arcgis_js_api/library/3.12/3.12/dojo'.

you are missing the dojo part!